# Real Analysis and Integration

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous, real-valued function on $[a,b]$ and define $H$ on $[a,b]$ by:
$$H(x)= \int_x^b f(t)\,dt \quad\text{for }x<b$$
Find $H'(x)$.

What I have so far is that since $f$ is continuous, $f$ is Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$.  And then, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, there exists an antiderivative of $f$, say $F$ such that $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$.

From FTC, I also know that $\int_a^b f(t)\,dt=F(b)-F(a)$.

Also, I know from properties of integrals that $-H(x)=\int_b^x f(t)\,dt$. And eventually, I think $H'(x)=f(x)$.

I just don't quite know how to fill in the gaps. If anyone could give me some insight, that would be great.

Also, If someone could tell me how to type ∫ with upper and lower bounds, as to make reading and understanding this question easier, that would be great too! Thank you!!

Comment: In LaTeX, integral signs are given by `\int` and definite integrals can be written using `\int_a^b`.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, and if $0 < x < b$, then if we let $G(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) \mathrm{d}t$, then $G'(x) = f(x)$. That should be all you need to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Just a sketching hint: the derivative of the integral $\int_b^x \! f(t) \ \text d t$ will be $f(x)$ by the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements).

Comment: it would be $-f(x)$ here.

Comment: Since H(x)= ∫bxf(t)dt Then, by letting some F(x) be an antiderivative of f(since one exists, as f is continuous), say F(x) = ∫xbf(t) dt then F'(x) = f(x) and H(x) = -F(x) so H'(x) = -F'(x) = -f(x).  Is that it?

Comment: I cant get the integral type right still.

Comment: -f(x) should be correct, yes!